# C# Same Datetime, 2 tick values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I'm creating a CRUD with Asp.net and Entity Framework.

When I try get LastModification DateTime for same User, I get two differents values.

[image: 19/05/2016 - Tick 1]

[image: 19/05/2016 - Tick 2]

I don't know why I get two differents values for same Datetime.

Comment: The milliseconds are different. `833` for one and `834` for another. Also, one is local time, the other is unspecified.

Comment: @Icemanind Yep,. but i get from same user, and same method... 

user = _database.Users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == Id);

Comment: Then the issue isn't with DateTime. There must be an issue in how you are pulling the data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference of milliseconds in both datetime. Please check the article below from MSDN for more information on this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

**Update**

What is worth noting here is that:
***There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond***

So, now when you look at the two Ticks Values, you should see this is the difference that you get.

**Edit 2**

Also, just to mention. The two records are clearly different. Look at value inside ***Kind***. One is **Local** and other is **Unspecified**

This could happen when you are doing something different while pulling the record. So, the issue is not really with the datetime itself.

Comment: I know, but is the same value on Sql server. And I get the value always same way.

Comment: Please share your code so we can further look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved that issue saving and pulling the datetime in ticks on SQL Server. It's a dirty solution, but I get always the same value...

Comment: It depends on if you are using `datetime` or `datetime2(7)`, if you do the 2nd one it should be able to round trip.

Comment: If you have solved it. Please share your answer and select it as accepted answer so it could help others as well.